# How can I get the depth of the tree in RPART model?

Tags: r, tree, rpart

Suppose I build a toy tree model with RPART, how can I get the depth of the tree?

```
library(rpart)
library(partykit)
fit=rpart(factor(am)~.,mtcars,control=rpart.control(cp=0,minsplit = 1))
plot(as.party(fit))
```

I know how to count the leaves, for binary tree, we can approximate the depth by number of leaves, but it is not directly the depth of the tree.

```
sum(fit$frame$var=="<leaf>")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

rpart has a unexported function `tree.depth` that gives the depth of each node in the vector of node numbers passed to it.  Using data from the question:

```
nodes <- as.numeric(rownames(fit$frame))
max(rpart:::tree.depth(nodes))
## [1] 2
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer is perfect. But how did you know unexported function? you checked source code?

Comment: Yes.  One has to check the source. https://github.com/cran/rpart/blob/4a009f14f2b342baa2df55854d578a45b16a17da/R/zzz.R

Comment: if you checked source, could you see if you can answer this question? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248706/why-i-cannot-achieve-100-accuracy-in-my-simple-training-data-with-cart-model

Comment: @hxd1011, Hi, could you please help me with me question,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228786/rpart-find-number-of-leaves-that-a-cp-value-to-pruning-a-tree-would-return   Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Given the way splits from node `n` are named (`2 * n` and `2 * n * 1`),
[vignette](http://www.milbo.org/rpart-plot/prp.pdf) page 26, tree depth can be
obtained truncating the log in base 2 of the max node:

```r
library(rpart)

fit <- rpart(factor(am)~., mtcars, control=rpart.control(cp = 0, minsplit = 1))
plot(fit, margin = 0.1)
text(fit, digits = 3, all = TRUE, use.n = TRUE, cex = 0.8, pretty = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
row.names(fit$frame) |> 
  as.integer() |> 
  max() |> 
  log(base = 2) |> 
  trunc()
#> [1] 2
```

As a matter of fact, `rpart:::tree.depth()` uses a similar idea to compute the
depth of each node

```r
rpart:::tree.depth
#> function (nodes) 
#> {
#>     depth <- floor(log(nodes, base = 2) + 1e-07)
#>     depth - min(depth)
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x000002b48f733c48>
#> <environment: namespace:rpart>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-14 with [reprex
v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>